# g++ default header include list

Tags: linux, gcc, include, g++, embedded-linux

While performing a compilation with cross g++ in a Linux machine ( lubuntu 11.10 ) in verbose mode, I can see the list of the default include header directories:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/opt/eldk-4.2/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/include
/opt/eldk-4.2/ppc_4xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/opt/eldk-4.2/ppc_4xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/powerpc-linux
/opt/eldk-4.2/ppc_4xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/backward
/opt/eldk-4.2/usr/../ppc_4xx/usr/include
```

Executing the very same g++ binary in another Linux machine (lubuntu 12.10), I get another different list, with less elements:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/opt/eldk-4.2/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/include
```

and in which some of the elments seem bad constructed, like the following:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/ppc_4xx/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/includ../include/c++/4.2.2"
```

The result is that some code compiling on the first system is not compiling on the second because some headers are not found.

Why is this happening?. Where does this list come from?. Who is responsible for constructing it?. Is it possible to easily change it?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run it as `g++ -v -H` and it will tell you a lot...

Answer (score 5):

You can add directories to the default search path by setting environment variables:

- `C_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C header files)
- `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C++ header files).

Alternatively, [you can create and edit specfile](http://www.mingw.org/node/25) and place it where G++ looks for them. You can check the path with `strace gcc`.

[Additional documentation on specfiles on GCC page.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Spec-Files.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any place where the default directories are stored. They've been probably built into the compiler.

Comment: I doubt it is stored into the compiler, as executing the same binary in different machines produce a different result

Comment: It is built in to the compiler, but the paths are built-in as relative paths so they are relative to where the binary is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact some problem using ELDK 4.2. This is very likely connected to something that changed in ubuntu 12.04 as I have had the compiler run fine on the same computer before the upgrade.

My problem is that is seems to have forgotten /usr

ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/eldk-4.2/../ppc_82xx/usr/include"

It should be

/opt/eldk-4.2/usr/../ppc_82xx/usr/include

Which works perfectly on ubuntu 11.10.

I have tried both installing ELDK from the ISO and copying the installation from a working version in ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I found this, http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?3533926-Ubuntu+12.04+and+ELDK+4.1

Comment: I "solved" my problem by adding the missing path to the specs file. It is a hack, but. http://www.mingw.org/node/25. It should be noted the ELDK 4.2 worked on my ubuntu image that was upgrade from 11.04, but not on a freshly installed 12.04. There is some kind of incompatibility with how paths and links are resolved. My guess is the if a directoy doesn't end with / it will give different results somewhere in some library

Comment: I'm not sure that is a hack - a solution is required here that insulates the build environment from its host - otherwise builds will simply not be repeatable.   An environment configuration for your tools that can be version controlled with the project is a must.  

In fact, version controlling your tools is a good plan too.

Comment: The problem is that it should work already. THe underlying problem I think is that ELDK is built with dynamic libs. As such, when the hosts updates you can run into problems. I am pretty sure this is due to the fact that ubuntu 12.04 has update libc to 2.15. Even if you apply the above change to the spec (Which you shouldn't need because the paths are found relative from the gcc binary normally) you will get other issues with the compiler under 12.04 when it tries to find .so libs that are soft links. So for now I would suggest using an earlier ubuntu